# Nginx + Symfony. Basic auth except for a subfolder

Tags: php, symfony, nginx, basic-authentication

I have a symfony app under nginx server. I want to enable basic http auth but exclude everything inside the /api/ url request.

This is my current configuration for nginx:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /home/mysite/www/web;

    index app.php index.php index.html;

    server_name mysite.com;

    error_log  /home/mysite/logs/error.log  warn;
    access_log /home/mysite/logs/access.log;


    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }

    # PROD
    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
        include /etc/nginx/php-mysite.conf;

        # Protect access
        auth_basic "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }

    location ~ ^/app\.php/api/(.*) {
        include /etc/nginx/php-mysite.conf;
        auth_basic "off";
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
       deny all;
    }
}
```

In `/etc/nginx/php-mysite.conf` is the php-fpm configuration. It works well.

The problem is that it seems that every request is being handled by the the `^app.php(/|$)` location directive. I am unable to configure it to disable the auth request when accessing `/api/...` urls.

I've spend several hours without success.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I don't like this solution, but it works. What I've done is to check the request_uri in the location directive, and if it starts with /api then I enable the auth basic. I would like to use two separate locations for this purpose instead of an if inside the location.

This is the location directive, by default it is enabled and if the request matches ^/api/.*$ then the auth is set to off:

```
# PROD
location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
    include /etc/nginx/php-mysite.conf;

    # Protect access
    set $auth "Restricted";
    if ($request_uri ~ ^/api/.*$){
        set $auth "off";
    }

    auth_basic $auth;
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Helped me a lot for a Wordpress API project. Replace `api` with `wp-json` and the wordpress api is reachable while the regular wordpress website is password restricted!

Comment: Important to know: auth_basic can be set just once !